# Laravel 5.2 admin dashboard

Tags: php, laravel-5

Some laravel master's help needed.
I want to make admin account login and dashboard.

Out of the box laravel provides authentication with table `users`. I've added table `roles` and a column `users(role_id)` so i can differ users.
Many hours of searching didnt help cause in most cases it was dumb way of duplicating of native authentication with two tables for different users.

**Kernel.php**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'web',
        'auth',
    ],
];
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('admin', 'LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('admin', 'LoginController@authenticate');

    Route::get('dashboard', function () {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    });
});
```

**LoginController.php**

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('admin.login');
}

public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credential = [
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => $request['password']
    ];

    if (Auth::attempt($credential) && $this->authAdmin($credential['email']))
    {
        //SOMETHING I DONT KNOW YET
        //BUT THEN
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
}

protected function authAdmin($email = null)
{
    $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();

    if ($user->role_id == '2')
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When i go `/dashboard` i see basic login form and when i enter credentials i become logged, but session is the same with simple user. I am not sure about my **LoginController** methods. The question is: how to differ sessions to make admin account ? Some advices about above code desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was pretty close. So here's my solution to my own question.

First of all i've added method to check the role to user model **User.php**

In my case it looks like

```
public function isAdmin() {
    $st = false;
    if ($this->role_id == 2) {
        $st = true;
    }
    return $st;
}
```

Then i've crated middleware **IsAdmin.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class IsAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin()) { //check the proper role
            return $next($request);
        }
        else {
            return response()
                ->view('admin.forbidden')
                ->header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        }
    }
}
```

Next i've edited **Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class, //my middleware
];
```

**routes.php** looks like

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function() {
        Route::get('/dashboard', 'LoginController@dashboard');
    });
});
```

And **LoginController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function dashboard()
    {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

You can simply restrict or allow actions to any role this way. I hope this  will help someone.